# How to delete user from all secondary groups in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, users, group

According to `pw usermod` documentation:

> -G    grouplist  Set secondary group memberships for an account.  grouplist
>              is a comma, space, or tab-separated list of group names or
>              group numbers.  The user is added to the groups specified
>              in grouplist, and removed from all groups not specified.
>              The current login session is not affected by group member-
>              ship changes, which only take effect when the user recon-
>              nects.  Note: do not add a user to their primary group with
>              grouplist.

I tried

```
pw usermod test_user -G ''
```

but that command has no effect at all.

Workaround:
Delete a user from all groups except one:

```
pw usermod test_user -G test_group
```

and then delete user from that group:

```
pw groupmod test_group -d test_user
```

But this requires creating a trash group or knowing one of users groups. Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there doesn't seem an easy way. However, it is trivial to get a comma separated list of secondary groups for a user:

```
pw usershow $user -P | grep Groups: | cut -w -f 3
```

You can iterate over that easily enough and use:

```
pw groupmod $group -d $user
```